# AWS SQS with a single worker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, serverless

I'm struggling to establish a queue in an AWS environment where the tasks are consumed by **one** Lambda / worker.

AWS Lambda [automatically scales](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/scaling.html) however I don't want that. The trouble is the function makes several complex changes to a database and there can be *race conditions*. Unfortunately this is out of my control.

Therefore it is easier to ensure there is **one worker** instead of solving the complex SQL issues. So what I want is whenever there is a messages in the queue, a single worker receives the messages and completes the tasks sequentially. Order does not matter.

Comment: In theory, SQS messages are consumed by just one consumer, isn't it?

Comment: When I connect it to my lambda, it just horizontally scales and the messages are processed concurrently... or is it in parallel? This will cause race conditions for me.

Answer (score 2):

Set the [concurrency limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/concurrent-executions.html) on the Lambda function to `1`.

Comment: Good point- although I'd always understood that the if you do this SQS still dispatches the messages at 5/time, and 4 of these will fail and be re-driven, which (depending on your configuration) will end up with them just being dumped into the DLQ (ref: https://www.jeremydaly.com/serverless-consumers-with-lambda-and-sqs-triggers/)

Answer (score 0):

As you've noticed that 'built-in' SQS starts with a minimum of five workers and scales up.

I have two suggestions for you, however:

- If you only have one shard, then kinesis (with a batch-size of one item), will ensure sequential, ordered, execution. This is because Kinesis is parallel by shard (and one shard can take 1000 records/second, so it's probably fine to only have one!) and the built-in lambda trigger takes a customisable batch size (which can be 1) and waits for it to complete before taking the next batch.
- If you *need* to use SQS, then the "old" way of integrating (prior to the SQS trigger) will give you a "most likely one" and sequential execution. This is when you *actually* trigger your lambda on a [Scheduled CloudWatch Event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html), which allows you to have a single lambda checking the queue every X (configured by you). The challenge here is if X is shorter than the amount of time it takes to process a message, then a second lambda will run in parallel (there are patterns such as having X = the timeout of your lambda, and just having your lambda run for 5 minutes going through the queue one message at a time).

Comment: Thanks, I am now looking into Kinesis Data Stream. Another question I have is how to avoid duplicate records in the stream?

Comment: Btw the lambda could take a large batch to process one by one, as I think it is a better approach than each tasks triggering a lambda execution. Lambda's 15 minute timeout should be more than enough for the typical workloads expected.

Comment: That's up to you (there's unlikely to be much change in sum execution time, thus cost)- but you should notice that Kinesis cannot "acknowledge" so you either retry (or dump) the whole batch on error; which makes 1-by-1 sound more suitable for what I understand of your use case.

Comment: As for duplicates- if you need to de-duplicate, possibly the best pattern (noting that neither SNS or SQS do this either) is to use DynamoDb. Given that a task can be uniquely identified by an id, you can write the task to DDb and then use the 'INSERT' transactions on the dynamo stream (i.e. ignore the UPDATE/DELETE) which will only occur the first time the unique task id is called.

Comment: There's no need to switch from SQS to Kinesis for this, or to stop using the built-in SQS/Lambda integration. You simply need to set the concurrency limit to `1` in the Lambda function's settings.